# Proguard can't find referenced class?

Tags: android, proguard

I've been using proguard for a few months, and today I started getting this warning:

```
[proguard] Initializing...
[proguard] Warning: com.me.MyFragment: can't find referenced class com.me.MyFragment$1
...
```

and this is the code that's problematic:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public void foo() {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                ...
            });
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The OnClickListener is the $1 reference that's missing. But this code shouldn't be touched if the DEBUG boolean is set to false, so I don't see why proguard would be warning me here.

If I turn the boolean flag to true, then proguard runs ok without warning. Any idea how this could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ProGuard prints out this error after having read the input and before performing any processing. Apparently, the input contained com/me/MyFragment.class, but not its anonymous inner class com/me/MyFragment$1.class. You may want to start with a clean build. You should then make sure the build steps before ProGuard are running as they should: compilation, packaging,... You can check the input that is passed to ProGuard.

Comment: I am in the exact same situation right now and followed your advice to no avail. When opening the included Android library jar with the missing "XYZ$1" class I could see that the JAR file in fact does not contain such an anonymous class. It seems to be discarded on compilation. But where does ProGuard get that information from and why does it require the missing class when it is discarded and never used?

Comment: @Nobu Games The warning mentions which class (XYZ) is referring to which missing class (XYZ$1). Much like a compiler, ProGuard needs all referenced classes before it can start analyzing the code. If you recompile XYZ.java, all classes should be there; the compiler never discards any unused classes.

Comment: It seems a trivial advice to make always mvn clean package, but because Eclise is actively sabotaging maven, I often do it the dirty way. Clean package have solved the problem.